# Set vertical scroll on a container with unknown height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Is it possible to set a vertical scroll on a container **with unknown height** using flexbox?

I can not use `max-height` as it will limit the height to some number that will not fit all screen sizes.

Here is a simple example of what i need:

```
<div class="list flex-vertical">
  <header>Some header</header>
  <ul class="flex-vertical">
    <li>Item1</li>
    <li>Item2</li>
    <li>Item3</li>
    <li>Item4</li>
    ...
  </ul>
</div>
```

I would like only the `ul` to scroll and obviously i don't know the height of it.

[here is a pen](http://codepen.io/ftom2/pen/zrVWXr)

Comment: You can just set a `max-height`? Or what do you mean?

Comment: try removing `overflow: hidden` from the body...

Comment: you need at least a container with overflow-y visible

Comment: @fcalderan I've put overflow:hidden on purpose, i want only the inner list to scroll

Comment: @Evochrome - As i mentioned in the question, it's dynamic height, so i don't have a magic number to set as the max-height

Comment: @fatman but what is the purpose of the scrollbar then? What are the conditions? Provide more information please

Comment: @Evochrome - I really don't see whats not to understand, I would like only the inner list (<ul>) to scroll if it goes out of screen boundaries. I don't want the body or the outer container to scroll, only the inner list, and  i would like to do it without setting a fixed height anywhere

Answer (score 3):

`flex` has some short comings/bugs/flaws, or what ever to call them, and need an inner absolute element to force the scroll.

```css
html, body{
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.list{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}
header {
  flex: 0;
}
.vertical {
  flex: 1;
  position: relative;  
}
.scroll {  
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="list flex-vertical">
  <header>Some header</header>
  <div class="vertical">
    <ul class="scroll">
      <li>Item1</li>
      <li>Item2</li>
      <li>Item3</li>
      <li>Item4</li>
      <li>Item5</li>
      <li>Item6</li>
      <li>Item7</li>
      <li>Item8</li>
      <li>Item9</li>
      <li>Item10</li>
      <li>Item11</li>
      <li>Item12</li>
      <li>Item13</li>
      <li>Item14</li>
      <li>Item15</li>
      <li>Item16</li>
      <li>Item17</li>
      <li>Item18</li>
      <li>Item19</li>
      <li>Item20</li>
      <li>Item21</li>
      <li>Item22</li>
      <li>Item23</li>
      <li>Item24</li>
      <li>Item25</li>
      <li>Item26</li>
      <li>Item27</li>
      <li>Item28</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That would work, but i need to set height for all parent containers, and  I was hoping to avoid it since I have a lot of them :(

Comment: @fatman The code sample you have in your question needs height. If the code you really will use this technique with have it from content, it will work as well, else you need to set height one way or the other, where in rare situations a script will be needed.

Comment: yeah figured that much, i wrote a script that calculates the heights, but was hoping there might be a way with flex to ease the pane

Comment: @fatman If you would post a slightly bigger code base showing how the actual problem looks like, I/we might be able to give a better answer.